# Gitlab-ci cannot connect to local server port 5432

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

i have read a lot of answers in forums about this question but noone gives me solution. 
I want to run rspec on gitlab-ci but every time get an error

> could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"test_vibly", "user"=>"here's my username", "password"=>here's my password}
>   rake aborted!

absolutely 100% that postgres server is running on my machine

> tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5432         *.*                    LISTEN
>
> tcp6       0      0  fe80::1%lo0.5432       *.*                    LISTEN
>
> tcp6       0      0  ::1.5432               *.*                    LISTEN

- brew services list:

> Name       Status  User    Plist
>
> mongodb    stopped
>
> postgresql started rubyguy /Users/rubyguy/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist

- gitlab-ci.yml file

  ```
  services:
    - postgres:latest


  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: vibly
    POSTGRES_USER: <%= ENV["DB_USER"] %>
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>

  rspec:
    stage: test
    image: g3dinua/node-ruby:2.3.3
    script:
      - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
      - apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y locales mysql-client
      - echo "en_US UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
      - locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
      - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
      - export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
      - export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
      - mkdir -p /cache/bin
      - ruby -v
      - gem install bundler
      - 'bundle_path=$(which bundle)'
      - bundle install --jobs $(nproc) --path=/cache/bundler
      - "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create --trace"
      - "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:schema:load --trace"
      - "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:test:prepare --trace"
      - "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec/"
    tags:
      - ruby
  ```

Comment: Can you connect locally with `psql -U $DB_USER -W -h localhost -p 5432 -d vibly` ?

Comment: yes, after this line postgres ask me a password and after i enter it i'm connected